# Creating bandwidth with multiple WAN and LAN ports

Tags: lan, wan, load-balancing

I have a network with roughly 50 machines all on one LAN, consisting of Linux, Windows, and server machines.

I have an untangled u150 firewall/router.

I have the ability to add an additional WAN & LAN port to get more bandwidth.

What is the best way for all machines internally to stay on the same LAN, yet gain the additional bandwidth?

Part I am struggling with. If I assign the LAN ports 10.20.30.1 & and 10.20.30.2, everything will work I believe, but I manually have to then set the default gateway on machines to one or the other.

Is this true, or am I not thinking about this correctly?

Comment: You need to approach this in a more methodical way.  Are you talking about lack of bandwidth between the 50 machines?  Or Internet bandwidth?  What is your ISP bandwidth?  Please provide us with more information about your network. Most importantly, tell us why you think there is a bandwidth problem?  What you are suggesting to do will not help at all.

Comment: Internet bandwidth. Bandwidth between stuff within the LAN is 100% fine. I believe the internet bandwidth is 100mb per link. The reason for giving more bandwidth is, it's there if i want to incorporate it and download speeds from external devices is very slow along with 200+ rdp sessions running.

Comment: Your firewall is likely the choke point.  If your firewall can't forward packets fast enough, adding bandwidth won't help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need some kind of load balancing.

Two WAN links can only be aggregated when they're from the same ISP and they support link aggregation.

In all other cases you need to implement load balancing on the router. Depending on your router's capabilities, this can be accomplished to dividing traffic by least used link, by source IP address or network, by service, or by any other way you can define a rule for (policy-based routing).

On the LAN side, once you exceed the bandwidth of a single port, you can either aggregate multiple links (LAG) or use multiple ports that are each dedicated to one or more internal VLANs.

If you set up multiple VLANs *and* expect a lot of traffic between these VLANs, running that traffic through the firewall might not be desired. Then, you should set up a central L3 switch as default gateway to route between the VLANs.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this Untangle's NG firewall using their paid module [WAN Balancer](https://www.untangle.com/shop/WAN-Balancer/)

Comment: Product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic on SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: Ron, I am not sure I follow as why you think that. He is using a untangle U150. That is a device that runs Untangle NG firewall.